# Is this SQL query correct? I'm using a LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, join

Using a type of join, return first name, last name, order number of customer records created after Nov 1, 2010. Include order numbers in the 3rd column only if that customer has placed any orders.

```
   SELECT c.firstname,
          c.lastname,
          o.ordernumber 
     FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Orders o ON c.customerid = o.customerid
    WHERE o.orderdate > '2010-01-01'
      AND o.ordernumber IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Be careful, Nov 1, 2010 is not '2010-01-01' as written above.

Comment: You said: `customer records created after Nov 1, 2010`, but in your query you are checking `Orders.OrderDate` column (for a different date too, as Bryan has neatly observed). Is that column really connected with creating customer records? Or what does 'creating customer records' mean actually?

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as an Inner Join.  Example:

```
SELECT c.firstname,
c.lastname,
o.ordernumber FROM   Customers c
Inner JOIN Orders o
ON     c.customerid = o.customerid
where o. orderdate > '01-01-2010'
```

should return the same results.  `LEFT JOIN` is used when you want to return `CUSTOMER` regardless of whether they have a corresponding `ORDER` record.  If you only want customers that have orders just user the `INNER JOIN`.

As @Bryan points out, you might want to look at converting your date to match your format.  [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) shows how to convert a varchar to a datetime depending on the format.

Answer (score 0):

The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will result in a row for each row in the `Customer` table. This can be seen better in the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join). The use of `INNER JOIN` will only return rows for customers who have corresponding orders.

Answer (score 0):

Without testing this, I think you won't need "and ordernumber is not null".

You'll end up with:

```
FirstName| LastName| OrderNumber
John       Smith     1
John       Smith     2
Joe        Bloggs    NULL     <-- Joe has no orders
```

What you are saying is "Show me everyone and their orders. If someone doesn't have any orders, show them anyway"

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct, the WHERE condition will evaluate to false if there is no order, so customers with no orders won't be included (I assume you want all customers, since you write "Include order numbers in the 3rd column only if that customer has placed any orders.", so using INNER JOIN as others suggest would be incorrect).

You probably want to just drop the `o.ordernumber IS NOT NULL` condition.

Answer (score 0):

If by 'customer records' you indeed mean 'customer orders', then maybe your query should look like this:

```
   SELECT c.firstname,
          c.lastname,
          o.ordernumber 
     FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Orders o ON c.customerid = o.customerid
      AND o.orderdate > '2010-01-01'
                  /* or '2010-11-01', if you want Nov 1, 2010 */
```

This will output all the customers. The third column will contain either NULL or an order number.

Keep in mind that if a customer has more than one order after the given date, his/her name will appear in the list more than once accordingly, with different order number each time.